# regex to match part of a prometheus label

Tags: regex, prometheus, re2

I've been trying to save the hostname of a FQDN (ie the "xxx" part only from "xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.sub.domain.com") to another label in prometheus for a couple of hours and I just can't figure it out. None of the the regex I'm using are doing anything:

```
^([-A-z0-9]+)
^([^.]+)
^[^.]*
```

Tested the following on https://relabeler.promlabs.com/ with object label **address**: "xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.sub.domain.com"

```
- source_labels: [__address__]
  regex: "from above"
  target_label: instanceID
```

None of the aforementioned regex change anything.

How can I get "instanceID: xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx" from "**address**: xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.sub.domain.com" in prometheus 2.40 relabel_configs?

Answer (score 1):

```
([^\.]+)\..+
```

Played around a bit and this works just fine